# Asking help for understanding some steps in Stone-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading Rudin's *Principle of mathematical analysis*, in the section 'Stone-Weierstrass theorem', there is a steps that I don't understand:

$$
P_{n}(x)=\int_{-1}^{1} f(x+t)Q_{n}(t) dt
$$
by changing variable,
$$
P_{n}(x)=\int_{-x}^{1-x} f(x+t)Q_{n}(t) dt
$$

I don't understand what Rudin did here, could anyone explain it to me?

Comment: There are assumptions on $f$ that you should also include here. (If I recall correctly, $f$ is supported on $[0,1]$ or something like that.)

Comment: $f$ is on [0,1] and $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Also $f$ is defined to be 0 outside [0,1]. I think (not sure) the last one is irrelevant here.

Comment: $Q_n(t)=Q_n(-t)$ since $Q_n(s):=c_n(1-x^2)^n$. May be we need this.

Comment: **Already answered in another question**. The answer(https://math.stackexchange.com/a/179822/120721) uses the fact that $f$ is defined to be 0 outside [0,1].